# Determining current Activity Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an issue in my app. I'm creating a sort of improvised menu bar that has to be included in all activities in my app, I want to determine which activity is loaded currently so that via an intent the application will link to the Activity that is linked to a button:

```
public void graphAction()
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this, GraphActivity.class );
    this.startActivity(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider using ActionbarSherlock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/)
But I do not understand why you would want the currently active activity?
If the graphAction is not in the activity but some custom object, just pass the activity there (or better: use a context object, Activities should not be passed around)

Comment: I want the current Activity because in the creation of the Intent (to make the app go to the next Activity when button is clicked) it is asked to refer to the current activity

Answer (score 2):

try below function to get the top activity name.

```
  private String getTopActivityName() {
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // get the info from the currently running task
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        return componentInfo.getShortClassName();
    }
```

Comment: That returns a string with the activity name, how can I convert that name into an activity variable that can be used in the creation of the intent?

Comment: Try these, 
Get intent should work in your case: 

final Intent intent = getIntent(); startActivity(intent);

If parent activity is A then save intent into temporary varible into A and OnResume call of A, call the same saved intent.

Or you can use conponentInfo.packagename & classname.